# Resolved: Idle RPMs fluctuate and engine hesitation

Tags: toyota, stall, idle, rav4, hesitation

I am kind of stumped.

I have a 1996 Toyota Rav4 that is acting weird. Let me start with the list of recent repairs.

I gave it:

- a tune-up (new sparks, wires, distributor cap and rotor)
- changed the radiator
- cleaned the EGR valve, and
- recently changed the thermostat.

After all this the engine started revving up and down when idling. If I try to drive the car while it is still idling it stalls a lot. However the car still stalls a bit when it is finally warmed up but not as frequent nor as hard.

I started looking on the web what it could be and still no luck. So far I have:

- cleaned the throttle body and the IAC valve
- installed a new PCV valve
- checked for vacuum leaks via a smoke test and the sparking carb cleaner method - I just tried a new MAP sensor.

The only check engine light codes the car throws are P0300 and P0301-4.

Anyone have any idea what it could be?

Resolved (11/15/15): It was a loose camshaft position sensor. Plugged it in and now the car runs fine.

Comment: Does the situation at idle improve when you turn on the air conditioning?

Comment: It is cold outside so I have not turned on the AC, plus it really doesn't work. I will try that anyways and report back.

Comment: Maybe try looking here [http://repairpal.com/OBD-II-Code-P0301](http://repairpal.com/OBD-II-Code-P0301).  Of the common causes listed there that you haven't tried, it looks like weak fuel pressure (fuel pump) or ignition timing.

Comment: You say it revs up and down, what are the high and low revs (approx)?

Comment: @HandyHowie It starts at 2000 rpms and drops like 250-500 rpms when it stalls. It is stops idling at about 750 rpm - 1000 rpm.

Comment: Have you cleaned the Mass Air Flow (MAF) sensor?  Should be just after the air filter in the intake hose.

Comment: When you talk about driving the car while it is still idling, do you really mean while it is cold?

Comment: You said that you cleaned the throttle body, can I just verify that you meant the internals?

Comment: Yeap I meant cold and yes I cleaned the inside with air intake cleaner.

Comment: @HandyHowie I am starting to thing it is a timing issue because it still jerks after the engine is cold.

Comment: It might be worth checking the temperature sensors, iif it is a lot worse when it is cold.  There will probably be a sensor for the gauge on the dash, but more importantly there will be one for the engine ECU.

Comment: I just put in a new coolant sender unit. I think I still have the old one, so I might try the old one to see if it stops the problem.

Comment: Could you create an answer for your own question and award yourself the right answer?  It will help the site statistics.  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Quite often surging like this is caused by not enough air getting passed the butterfly valve in the throttle body when the butterfly is closed.  Under normal circumstances, there should be a very small gap around the butterfly to allow the air required for idle.  If the butterfly is closed too much, the revs will drop too far forcing the engine ECU to open the idle control valve (IAC).  It will then try to back off the air through the IAC, but since not enough air is getting passed the butterfly for idle, the revs will drop to far and so the surging cycle repeats.

Either the throttle body internals are dirty, which you say you have already cleaned, or the throttle just needs adjusting due to wear.  There should be an adjustment screw on the throttle body that should allow you to open the butterfly valve slightly.  Hopefully this will stop the surging.

Comment: Hmm I just adjusted it and no luck. However the CEL came on, I will report back what I get.

Comment: When you adjusted it, did the revs increase?

Comment: Yes, they did increase but the rpms dip and comes back quickly while it is idling.

Comment: Can it hold a steady rpm when you press the throttle a little?

Comment: Yeah when I press the throttle it holds the rpms.

Comment: Hmm now that I give it a try it still jump when why I press the throttle down. The codes were the same.

Comment: I spotted a ground cable that is broken, idk what it is supposed to go to tho.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I have a 1996 CR-V. Have been reading around the net for fluctuating RPM at start. When I read what you changed. There is a similarity. Mine started after I put in a new thermostat. I am going to take a look at the thermostat. You try that too.